# Mixin in Stylus

Tags: css, stylus

There are two elements with two common properties but their values are various below,

```
EL_a
  p1 v1_a
  p2 v2_a

EL_b
  p1 v1_b
  p2 v2_b
```

Can we make a proper mixin in stylus to pass the respective values below?

```
EL_a
  mixin v1_a v2_a

EL_b
  mixin v1_b v2_b
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you want, maybe this can help you:

```
<div class="DivD">
   MIX
</div>

mixing0(wid = 20px, col = #e33)
    width: wid
    color: col
.DivD
    mixing0 200px green
```

http://stylus-lang.com/docs/mixins.html